# i want to add multiple variables in a string type variable and on every value will be start from next line in swift 4

Tags: swift, string, concatenation, swift4.2

i have a variable
var result : String = ""

now i am getting different string in different variables and i want to assign these values to my result variable and each value will be in new line. i.e here is my code

result = result + (method ?? "")
        result = result + "\n"

```
    result = result + (content ?? "" )
    result = result + "\n"

    result = result + (acceptHeader ?? "")
    result = result + "\n"

    result = result + (url ?? "")
    result = result + "\n"

    result = result + (timeStamp ?? "")
    result = result + "\n"

    result = result + (publicKey ?? "")
```

AND I AM PRINTING THIS result IT IS PRINTING ME THIS

```
get
application/json
https://www.google.com
2020-04-07T11:08:34.989Z
```

but when i assign this value to some variable it is giving this 
get\n\napplication/json\nhttps://www.google.com\n2020-04-07T11:08:34.989Z\n

I want that my value will be assigned to the variable will be as it is printed. i.e like this

```
get
application/json
https://www.google.com
2020-04-07T11:08:34.989Z
```

Comment: It's not clear what you get in your second variable, is this what you see in the debugger or when you print the variable? To me it looks like the expected behaviour

Comment: the string in which i am appending my values result I want to send thsi result in a func as a string and its values to be like 
get
application/json
https://www.google.com
2020-04-07T11:08:34.989Z

but i get like in 1 line which i don't want like this   .... get\n\napplication/json\nhttps://www.google.com\n2020-04-07T11:08:34.989Z\n

Comment: yes i am getting this in 1 line but i want to be every value in next line but it must be assigned to single variable.

Comment: But you have a new line character between each value so they are on different lines even though it is represented as one line in the debugger. Maybe what you need is to store the values in an array or struct. Since we don't know what you need this for it's hard to answer your question